# Azure Data Flow generic curation framework

Tags: azure-data-factory

I wanted to create a data curation framework using Data Flow that uses generic data flow pipelines.

I have multiple data feeds (raw tables) to validate (between 10-100) and write to sink as curated tables:

- For each raw data feed, need to validate the expected schema (based on a parameterized file name)
- For each raw data feed, need to provide the Data Flow Script with validation logic (some columns should not be null, some columns should have specifici data types and value ranges, etc.)
- Using Python SDK, create Data Factory and mapping data flows pipelines using the Data Flow Script prepared with the parameters provided (for schema validation)
- Trigger the python code that creates the pipelines for each feed, does validation, write the issues into Log Analytics workspace and tear off the resources at specific schedules.

Has anyone done something like this? What is the best approach for the above please?

My overall goal is to reduce the time to validate/curate the data feeds, thus I wanted to prepare the validation logic quickly for each feed and create python classes or Powershell scripts scheduled to run them on generic data pipelines at specific times of the day.

many thanks

CK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To validate the schema, you can have a reference dataset which will be having the same schema (first row) as of your main dataset. Then you need to use **“Get Metadata”** activity for each dataset and get the structure of each dataset. Your Get Metadata activity will look like this:
[image]

You can then use **“If Condition”** activity to matches the structure of both datasets using **equal Logical Function**. Your equal expression will look something like this:
[image]

If both datasets’ structure matches, your next required activity(like copy the dataset to another container) will be performed.
Your complete pipeline will look like this:
[image]

The script which you want to run on your inserted dataset could be performed using **“Custom”** activity.  You again need to create the linked service and it’s corresponding dataset for your script which you will run to validate the raw data. Please refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/tutorial-run-python-batch-azure-data-factory

To schedule the pipeline as per your specific pipeline will be take care by [Triggers in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers). A [schedule trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-schedule-trigger) will take care of your requirement of auto trigger your pipeline at any specific time.